# Python : get the size of a rendered web page

Tags: python, http

Is there a way to get the size of a rendered page via a python http request ?

I'm not sure my wording is correct but what I mean by "rendered page" is the size a browser would have to load (incl. images, css, ...). Not the length of the html code.

As a second priority, it would also be helpful to know the number of calls and if the page is gziped as this might impact the result of sizing the page in question.

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: This would certainly require to run the webpage inside a browser engine because today’s web pages often load content dynamically from running scripts. Just parsing the HTML recursively won’t cut it.

Comment: To actually simulate everything you'd need a fake web browser.. Maybe try selenium (a library for automation with browsers), or try parsing the script urls and stylesheet urls yourself, and loading them with requests (a library for making http requests). You probably won't get everything though if you do it that way (webpages today can be very dynamic).

Comment: The question then becomes: are you trying to the get the size for the purpose of loading in a webpage, or are you just trying to get all the elements recursively that are available in the HTML, ignoring everything that could happen in the Javascript?

Comment: Reading these first answers it seems that I should follow @Graham suggestion and simplify the issue by ignoring all asynchronous behaviour.

Comment: It's not necessarily that difficult, perhaps you can use Selenium WebDriver + Headless Chrome https://intoli.com/blog/running-selenium-with-headless-chrome/ I'm looking into this myself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written a Python script that does this with Selenium and a headless Chrome remote WebDriver:

[Here](https://github.com/jorgeorpinel/site-page-size-scrapper) (Feel free to clone or fork!)

The trick is to enable performance logging, fetch and parse the Network logs to calculate the full size of the web page. Something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver 

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
capbs = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
capbs.update({'loggingPrefs': {'performance': 'ALL'}, 'detach': False})
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:9515", capbs, options=options)
# ^ Requires chromedriver (server) running locally (on default port).

driver.get('https://www.baidu.com/')
logs = driver.execute('getLog', {'type': 'performance'})['value']
# Now analyze the Network logs as you prefer.
```

See https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network